# How to switch to desktop immediately when in fullscreen Chrome in macOS？

Tags: macos, google-chrome, macbook, fullscreen, macos-mojave

I like using Chrome in fullscreen mode and sometimes I want to switch to my desktop from Chrome immediately. I found the "hot corners" or "keyboard shortcut" I set are not working.

Is there any way to switch between fullscreen Chrome and Desktop without exiting fullscreen mode?

Comment: Question is unclear. By 'Desktop' do you mean Finder, or a specific, numbered 'Space'? Fullscreen apps have no numbers, so you cannot hot-key to switch to them [yet another really good reason to never use fullscreen] See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for a method to avoid fullscreen.

Comment: In Microsoft Windows, when i press win+D, it switched to 'desktop', the desktop with a wallpaper in background

Comment: So… what's your ultimate goal? The 'desktop' isn't really a single entity, you can have many, some numbered & some with fullscreen apps. I'm still not clear what you're trying to achieve… unless it's simply to look at the desktop background, in which case you just switch to a Space [desktop] with no apps in it.

Comment: Does `cmd` + `tab` not work for you?

Comment: thank you @Burgi ,it works.but that comes with a animation switching between spaces,not the way in ms-windows, maybe i'm not very get used to the windows-management in mac OS